# Does Gleam of Authority care if a creature gains extra counters?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The rules text on [Gleam of Authority](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gleam%20of%20Authority) is as follows:

> Enchant creature
>
> Enchanted creature gets +1/+1 for each +1/+1 counter on other creatures you control.
>
> Enchanted creature has vigilance and "{W}, {T}: Bolster 1."

If a creature were to gain more counters, would that enchantment also raise in power as well or just stay as it originally was?

Comment: I don't understand the first question; you appear to have accidentally some words.  Effects from putting artifacts/enchantments *where/on what*?

Comment: For example, if I placed Feral Invocation on a creature, would the effect of "Enchanted creature gets +2/+2." count as a counter, or would the card have to specifically say "Add X +1/+1 counters to creature"?

Comment: "Enchanted creature gets +2/+2" How do you get the idea that this has anything to do with counters? Especially since you are aware that there are other cards with different wordings that specifically instruct you to place  +1/+1 counters. If a card doesn't instruct you to place counters, you don't. Just follow the rules according to the normal rules of English; usually it is that easy.

Comment: Your first question has already been answered in [What counts as a counter?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/28091/1855)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are +1/+1 counters different from +1/+1 effects?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/18214/are-1-1-counters-different-from-1-1-effects)

Comment: Also related: [Double Gleam of Authority interaction](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23858/double-gleam-of-authority-interaction/23859#23859)

Comment: My second question still stands.

Comment: I would recommend asking just that question, because people have already linked to the answer to the first question.

Comment: Then I would suggest asking a new question. If your two questions are sufficiently different from each other, it's better to have them in 2 separate threads.

Comment: I've edited this down to just the second question, since the first is well covered already & known to the asker.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the enchanted creature would grow more powerful.

From the [Comprehensive Rules](http://magic.wizards.com/en/gameinfo/gameplay/formats/comprehensiverules):

> 604.1. Static abilities do something all the time rather than being activated or triggered. They are written as statements, and they’re simply true.
>
> 611.3a A continuous effect generated by a static ability isn’t “locked in”; it applies at any given moment to whatever its text indicates.